# SoapFault : Could not connect to host

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

i make a webservice in SOAP, is next

```
 $dataws=[
    'serie'=>$factura->serie,
    'folio'=>$factura->folio,
    'rfc'=>'xxxx123456',
    'key'=>'xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx'
    ];
    try {
    $url= 'https://portal3.xsa.com.mx/xsamanager/servicesb2b/CancelCFDIService?wsdl';              
    echo "<strong>url destino:<pre>";
    print_r ($url);
    echo "</pre></strong>";
        $client = new SoapClient(
            $url,
            array(
                'trace' => true,
                'exceptions' => true,
                'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                'stream_context'=> stream_context_create(array('ssl'=> array(
                            'verify_peer'=>false,
                            'verify_peer_name'=>false, 
                            'allow_self_signed' => true //can fiddle with this one.
                                 )
                            )
                )
            )
        );
        echo "<strong>Funciones existentes</strong> <pre>";
        print_r ($client->__getFunctions());
        echo "</pre>";
        $response = $client->cancelaCFDI($dataws);
```

when call function $client->__getFunctions(),
show this

> Funciones existentes
>       Array
>       (
>           [0] => cancelaCFDIResponse cancelaCFDI(cancelaCFDI $parameters)
>           [1] => mensajeResponse mensaje(mensaje $parameters)
>       )

show the functions, but call a function $client->cancelaCFDI($dataws) result this:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
SoapFault in FacturasController.php line 726:
Could not connect to host
in FacturasController.php line 726
at SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.cancel.manager.xsa.tralix.com"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:cancelaCFDI><ns1:serie>NUVEM</ns1:serie><ns1:folio>7</ns1:folio><ns1:key>b6769894-fef7-4c1c-9d60-176de99377c4</ns1:key></ns1:cancelaCFDI></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope> ', 'http://10.10.10.41:8080/xsamanager/servicesb2b/CancelCFDIService/', '', '1', '0')
at SoapClient->__call('cancelaCFDI', array(array('serie' => 'NUVEM', 'folio' => '7', 'rfc' => 'NHI120830831', 'key' => 'b6769894-fef7-4c1c-9d60-176de99377c4'))) in FacturasController.php line 726
at SoapClient->cancelaCFDI(array('serie' => 'NUVEM', 'folio' => '7', 'rfc' => 'NHI120830831', 'key' => 'b6769894-fef7-4c1c-9d60-176de99377c4')) in FacturasController.php line 726
```

i use the SoapClient of php